# Static fields - initialization and changing the value

Tags: c, static-members

Given the files:

```
// file: q7a.h
static int err_code = 3;
void printErrCode ();
///////////// END OF FILE /////////////////
// file: q7a.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "q7a.h"
void printErrCode ()
{
printf ("%d ", err_code);
}
///////////// END OF FILE /////////////////
// file: q7main.c
#include "q7a.h"
int main()
{
err_code = 5;
printErrCode ();
return 0;
}
///////////// END OF FILE /////////////////
```

The output is:

```
3
```

My Question is why the output is not 5?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

static global objects have scope limited to the current compilation unit. In this case you have two compilation units, one for each .c file, and each one has its own err_code.

Answer (score 3):

The `static` keyword for `err_code` specifies static linkage, i.e. the variable is local to the translation unit.

As you're compiling files `q7a.c` and `q7main.c` separately, there will be two different `err_code` variables. Hence the function `printErrCode` in `q7a.c` is using `err_code` visible only within the `q7a.c` scope.

Answer (score 0):

The output is not 5, **because global variables are bad**.

Try this, without declaring err_code anywhere and replacing the call in `main()`:

```
void printErrCode (int err_code)
{
    printf ("%d ", err_code);
}

int main ()
{
    /* ... */
    printErrCode(5);
    /* ... */
}
```